# Stripos issues in php4

Tags: php, php4

Please i have the following function for a contact form, but it shows the following error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: stripos() in" how can i fix it

```
function checkEmail($vEmail) {   

                    $invalidChars ="/:,;" ; 
                    if(strlen($vEmail)<1) return false;                                         //Invalid Characters
                    $atPos = stripos($vEmail,"@",1);                                    //First Position of @
                    if ($atPos != false) $periodPos = stripos($vEmail,".", $atPos);         //If @ is not Found Null . position
                    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($invalidChars); $i++) {                            //Check for bad characters 
                        $badChar = substr($invalidChars,i,1);       //Pick 1
                        if(stripos($vEmail,$badChar,0) != false)    //If Found
                            return false;
                    }
                    if ($atPos == false)                            //If @ is not found
                        return false;       
                    if ($periodPos == "")                           //If . is Null
                        return false;
                    if (stripos($vEmail,"@@")!=false)               //If @@ is found
                        return false;
                    if (stripos($vEmail,"@.") != false)             //@.is found
                        return false;
                    if (stripos($vEmail,".@") !=  false)            //.@ is found
                        return false;

                    return true;    
                }
```

Comment: The title mentions PHP 4 but the question is tagged PHP 5. Which is it?

Comment: Also that is a horrible way to validate an email!

Answer (score 3):

as you can see from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), `stripos()` only exists in PHP5. Anyways, your code doesn't need to chack case-insensitive because it only checks for `. @ / : , ;` - so you can just replace `stripos()` with [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

you could also add an own `stripos()` to your codebase, wich could look like thoe following (using [`strtolower()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and [`function_exists()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)):

```
if(!function_exists("stripos")){
  function stripos($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0){
    return strpos(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle), $offset)
  }
}
```

note that this is a very basic replacemend and might not give the same result like a real `stripos()` in each end every case. it's valid for basic usage, but i havn't done broad tests.

Comment: +1 even if the case insensitivity is needed, the arguments to `strpos()` can just be passed through `strtolower()` and you essentially have `stripos()`.

Comment: @MrCode: i thougth exactly the same and just added an example using `strtolower` to built an own `stripos`.

Answer (score 0):

stripos is a PHP 5 function, you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

stripos() is not available in PHP 4

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

> stripos
>
> (PHP 5)
>
> stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a
>   case-insensitive substring in a string

one of the comments in the manual shows this code, which might help you out:

```
if(!function_exists("stripos")){
    function stripos(  $str, $needle, $offset = 0  ){
        return strpos(  strtolower( $str ), strtolower( $needle ), $offset  );
    }/* endfunction stripos */
}/* endfunction exists stripos */

if(!function_exists("strripos")){
    function strripos(  $haystack, $needle, $offset = 0  ) {
        if(  !is_string( $needle )  )$needle = chr(  intval( $needle )  );
        if(  $offset < 0  ){
            $temp_cut = strrev(  substr( $haystack, 0, abs($offset) )  );
        }
        else{
            $temp_cut = strrev(    substr(   $haystack, 0, max(  ( strlen($haystack) - $offset ), 0  )   )    );
        }
        if(   (  $found = stripos( $temp_cut, strrev($needle) )  ) === FALSE   )return FALSE;
        $pos = (   strlen(  $haystack  ) - (  $found + $offset + strlen( $needle )  )   );
        return $pos;
    }/* endfunction strripos */
}/* endfunction exists strripos */
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned it's PHP5 only...

But that is a nasty email validation function, try this!

```
function validateEmail($email)
{
    return(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-+])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7})+$/", $email));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the valid email address timmy.o'toole@example.com, among others. The best way I've found to validate is to use Dominic Sayers is_email function http://isemail.info/

Comment: @Brian regex email validation does more harm than good, you'll end up losing genuine users or customers which don't match the pattern, for the sake of stopping some spam. If you need to know if the email is good, send a confirmation/activation link to it.

Comment: This is old but what if he is a student and cant send emails through the school server? I'm in this situation.